# How to erase a word with ink (forward, back, forward) in OneNote 2016?

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2010, microsoft-onenote-2016

With OneNote 2010, I can just write a line back and forth and it'll erase the word I wrote (forward, back, forward). But in OneNote 2016 I have to use the eraser. Boo

How to enable line erase (forward, back, forward) in OneNote 2016?  I really like not having to leave the screen or select a menu or even change my hand position.  Makes for quick note taking.

Answer (score 1):

File >> Options >> Advanced >> Pen

and then uncheck "Disable the scratch out gesture while inking."

!